# Logic behind loading Views with vuex dependencies vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logic, vuex

I have an API call that loads on my App.vue that populates my vuex store's state. The App.vue by default loads a Home.vue that displays images based on the store's state. The images load, but throw a lot of console errors before the state is populated. I'm not sure what the best logic is, in general, to delay loading VIEWS before the data they depend on is finished loading. Existing answers make sense for components but I can't bind data to the router-view, and don't think passing it in params makes sense. I'm a n00b.

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav-logo"></div>
        <div id="nav-links">
          <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> 
          <router-link to="/pokemon">Pokemon</router-link> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <router-view></router-view>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created(){
    this.init();
  },
  methods:{
    init(){
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchPokemon', 'gen1');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
//Home.vue
<template>
<div>
        <div id="pokemonAFront">
          <img :src="pokeImg[randomA].sprites.front_default" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="pokemonABack">
          <img :src="pokeImg[randomA].sprites.back_default" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      randomA: Math.floor(Math.random()* 20),
   },
  computed:{
    pokeImg(){
      return this.$store.state.pokemon
    }
}
</script>
```

```
//store/index.js
state:{
   pokemon:[]
},
mutations: {
  SET_POKEMON(state, pokemon){

      state.pokemon = pokemon;
    }
},
actions: {
    fetchPokemon(context, currentGen){
      context.commit('SET_POKEMON', pokeData.fetchPokemon(currentGen)) //api call
    }
}
```

What logic works best for delaying loading views/components when their vuex dependencies haven't loaded yet?

Comment: you can add `v-if` at `router-view` - to check if pokemon is not empty

Comment: my question wasn't clear: the issue is the views with state dependencies throw console errors because they load before the state is loaded. This solution doesn't block those erroes (specifically in the Home.vue TypeError: _vm.pokeImg[_vm.randomA] is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to render the dom only after the pokeImg gets populated from API:

```
 <div v-if="pokeImg.length > 0">
    <div id="pokemonAFront">
      <img :src="pokeImg[randomA].sprites.front_default" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="pokemonABack">
      <img :src="pokeImg[randomA].sprites.back_default" alt="">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Makes sense but the console still throws error "TypeError: _vm.pokeImg[_vm.randomA] is undefined" because it loads before the state is populates